# Promise { <pending> } on bcrypt

Tags: javascript, express, bcrypt

I am trying to validate a user's password using bcryptjs. I have this function which returns a Promise, however when I get to bycrypt.hash, all i get is `Promise { <pending> }` Therefore .then() will not execute on undefined. Please help, I've been stuck on this a while

```
userSchema.methods.verifyPassword = function (password, err, next) {
  const saltSecret = this.saltSecret;
  const a = async function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('hi4')
    console.log('this.saltSecret2', saltSecret);
    console.log(password);

    const hashed_pass = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltSecret);
    console.log('hash', hashed_pass);
    const valid = await bcrypt.compare(password, hashed_pass);
    if(valid){
      console.log('GOOD');
    }
  };
  a();
};
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! You forgot to resolve your promise when the hash was computed but not good.

Comment: `resolve(false);` when `hash == this.password` returns false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use async-await syntax to handle promises. It is less confusing. and gives the ability of quickly understanding someone else code.

you can make your function an async one. wait until bcrypt does its job

```
const password = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltSecret);
```

However bcrypt library provides a function to compare password and the hash

```
const valid = await bcrypt.compare(password, hashed_pass);
```

try this

```
async function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log('hi4')
  console.log(this.saltSecret);
  console.log(password);

  const hashed_pass = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltSecret);
  console.log('hash', hashed_pass);
  const valid = await bcrypt.compare(password, hashed_pass);
  if(valid){
    console.log('GOOD');
  }
};
```

Comment: I still receive 'undefined' when I call this function

Comment: Which variable is undefined?

Answer (score 1):

This line will always return a Promise.

```
console.log(bcrypt.hash(password, this.saltSecret));
```

You could always do something like this.

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, this.saltSecret);

    if (hash == this.password) {
        return resolve(true);
    }

    return reject();
});
```

Comment: I still receive 'undefined' when I call this function

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: Isn't async syntax syntactical sugar for promises? Why declare an async function as a promise?

Answer (score 0):

`bcrypt.hash` uses a callback, not a promise (that's what the `.then` is doing)

You should use it like so:

```js
bcrypt.hash(password, this.saltSecret, (err, hash) => {
    ...
});
```

Comment: `bcrypt.hash` [does return a promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#with-promises), so you don't need to use a callback

Comment: Yes, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Wrap inside a Promise

```
export const hashPassword = async (
      password: string,
      saltRounds = 10
    ): Promise<{
      salt: string;
      hash: string;
    }> => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds);
          return bcrypt.hash(password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            } else {
              resolve({
                salt,
                hash,
              });
            }
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          throw error;
        }
      });
    };
```